# HTML symbol in flash variable

Tags: html, flash, encoding, symbols

I got a Flash variable:

```
<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"title=$title\" />
```

`$title` is a string, but in this string I want to put: `ë` or in HTML `&euml;`.

But flash doesn’t like it.
How to fix this?
thnx, 
stefan

Answer (score 1):

Did you try entitizing the &? For example, instead of

```
&euml;
```

your value would be

```
&amp;euml;
```

Or it could be an encoding issue in your page. Or it could be that you are loading from a document whose BOM is absent.

Edited to say: I just remembered the flashvars parameter (which I no longer use) takes an ampersand-delimited list of arguments, just like a query string in a URL. So ampersands are going to be problematic no matter how they're used. It might be easier to set up your SWF to load those values from Javascript through ExternalInterface in Flash/Flex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there should be any issues with `flashvars` using special characters like `ë`. I just did a quick test, and it worked perfectly.

Just make sure the html document where you define the `flashvars` is saved as `utf-8`, and you should be good.

Also, if you are displaying the loaded text in a dynamic text field, make sure you have the right characters embedded - otherwise they won't display.